# Scroll Bar in DropDownList IN ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I am binding a DropDownList with the DataTable from the BackEnd. If the DataTable contains more value then while selecting the DropDownList it looks very lengthy and it looks not good. Is there a way to use ScrollBar in DropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi check out the post will allow to control the element display by drop downlist :

[DropDownList (html select) vertical scrollbar – number of items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2011/05/02/dropdownlist-html-select-vertical-scrollbar-number-of-items.aspx)

Comment: link is broken...this is why link only answers are frowned upon

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that with the DropDownList control.  One option would be to build a custom control that would do this.

Try googling for DropDownList adding scroll bars.  [adding scrollbar to dropdownlist](http://forums.asp.net/t/1226413.aspx) has a discussion about ways to do that.

Here's a search on MSDN - [DropDownList scroll bars](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=DropDownList+scroll+bars&x=0&y=0)